# how to handle this string and extract data out of it

Tags: php, explode

```
$string='eDreams 459   Travel Up 464   AirAfrica 464   Available at  459  Available at  464  Available at  464  Available at  473  Available at  478  Available at  479  Available at  498';
how to get data like:
array =
  0 => string 'eDreams' (length=6)
  1 => string '459'
array=
  0 => string 'Travel Up' (length=6)
  1 => string '464'
array = 
  0 => string 'AirAfrica' (length=6)
  1 => string '464'
```

how to do this i tried this with explode it works fine but not accurate help me please ?

Comment: what about others like :- `Available at  459` how they will comes in output array?

Comment: where does this initial string come from? Have you done any pre-processing of the data before this point?

Comment: @Anant yes i just want first three.but Available at can come at number three position so aw method that can adjust to every possible output.

Comment: I am unable to understand you. please explain with editing your expected output

Comment: @RamRaider no just parsed it and stored it as it is but now i have to do above mention.

Comment: @Anant i just want to get first three names with their int values

Comment: @Anant Available at 459 should aslo be coming with in two index of an array like:
'array = 
0 =>Available
1 =>459'

Comment: can you explain what you mean by `"no just parsed it and stored as it is"` - was this from a call to an API? Was this from a db? Was it from a scrape? Knowing the original format of the data might make the solution easier.

Comment: @RamRaider from a db man

Comment: OK - if you queried the database and generated the string as shown here then it should be possible to generate the string on a better format than this - or parsed directly into the desired array output rather than trying to fudge around with the string as it is.

Comment: the thing is like i mentioned above that i have only this string to deal with so i just can only fudge with this string to get what i want, do you get it now ?@RamRaider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way.. it's not pretty. I hope it helps you.

```
<?php
$string = "eDreams 459   Travel Up 464   AirAfrica 464   Available at  459  Available at  464  Available at  464  Available at  473  Available at  478  Available at  479  Available at  498";
$array = explode(" ", $string);
$final_array = array();
$found = false;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (ctype_digit($value)){
        $final_array[count($final_array)-1][] = (int)$value;
        $found = false;
    } else {
        if ($found == false){
            $final_array[] = array($value);
            $found = true;
        } else {
            $final_array[count($final_array)-1][0] .= " " . $value;
        }
    }
}
print_r($final_array);
?>
```

I wouldn't use something like this. Maybe you can get a better result from db directly.

Comment: amazing thanks for this and i have to use this as i have no other options. Many thanks

Comment: I forgot to add an if in the else.. It should be something like
} else {
     if ($value != '') {
          //the rest of the code

Otherwise you get some extra spaces

Comment: no what i was missing was ctype_digit function :) i did the rest.
you made my day thanks

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with this solution...

```
$string = 'eDreams 459   Travel Up 464   AirAfrica 464   Available at  459  Available at  464  Available at  464  Available at  473  Available at  478  Available at  479  Available at  498';

$arr = [ ]; 

$name = '';

$number = '';

$count = strlen( $string );

$reset = 0;

for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ )
{
    if ( is_numeric( $string[ $i ] ) )
    {
        $reset = 1;
        $number.= $string[ $i ];
    }
    else
    {
       if ( $reset == 1 )
        {
            $arr[] = [ trim( $name ), trim( $number ) ];
            $name = '';
            $number = '';
            $reset = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            $name.= $string[ $i ];
        }
    }
}
print_r( $arr );
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the elements you want to isolate into separate arrays are separated by several spaces or a tab shift, and the array elements themselves are separated by a single space. If the strings are in fact formatted this way, you can use the `split()` function to pull those elements into an array or several arrays. For example:

```
$split_pattern = "   ";
$array = split($split_pattern, $string);
```

Which will result in array that looks like:

```
array =
   0 => string 'eDreams 459'
   1 => string 'Travel Up 464'
   ...
   4 => string 'Available at'
   5 => string '459'
   etc...
```

You will need to `split()` each of these array elements again to create your arrays of format `0 => name, 1 => number`.

To deal with the `available at` entries, you can use the `array_keys()` function as such:

```
$pattern = "Available at";
$availables = array_keys($array, $pattern);
foreach ($availables as $available){
    $availableAt = $array[$available];
    $availableNum = $array[$available + 1];
}
```

So then `$availableAt` will always be `"Available at"`, but `$availableNum` will contain the number which is simply the next element in the array you originally `split()`. There are several ways you could accomplish this but I think this will be the most clear.

*References:*

- *http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php*
- *http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php*

Comment: yes @Josh this is what i already tried but can it be more specific like name on [0] index and int on [1] index. it

Comment: i tried it but available at disturbs it though thanks for you efforts :)

Comment: I edited my answer to offer a solution to the "Available at" items.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$string = "eDreams 459   Travel Up 464   AirAfrica 464   Available at  459  Available at  464  Available at  464  Available at  473  Available at  478  Available at  479  Available at  498";
$array = explode(" ", $string);
$final = [];

$str= [];
$num =[];

$temp = $array;
foreach($temp as $k=> $v){
    if(!empty($v)){ 
        if(is_numeric($v)){
            $num[] = $v;
            $final_array[] =[
                implode(" ",$str),implode(" ",$num)    
            ];

            $str= [];
            $num =[];
        }else{
            $str[] = $v;
        }
        $temp[$k] = "";
    }
}

print_r($final);
```